# This webpage has a redirect loop php cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

hello i am having trouble with my session cookie for my website it is a basic site but the problem is when the user is logged in it just starts a loop and crashes.

any help with this would be appreciated unfortunately this had to be done in standard php as the server does not support PDO(pdo not supported).

here is the code i have for my cookie user_id is the primary key and is unique for the users table in my database.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    header("location:bookTour.php");
} else {
    if($_SESSION["user_level"] !=2){
        header("location:failed.html");
    }
}
?>
```

here is the code from the login system i know it is not secure. im still in development.
also this cookie is from a page that a user cant use unless they are logged in with certain information.

```
<?php
session_start();

    $server = "server";
    $schema = "schema";
    $uid = "uid";
    $pwd = "pass";

  $password =$_POST["txt_password"];
  $email =$_POST["txt_email"];



mysql_connect($server , $uid , $pwd) or die ("server not found");
mysql_select_db($schema) or die ("Database not found");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = '$email' AND  password = '$password'";

    $record = mysql_query($sql) ;

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($record);

if(mysql_num_rows($record) == 0){
    die(header("location: login.html"));


}else if(mysql_num_rows($record) == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($record);
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
    $_SESSION["user_level"] = $row["user_level"];
    header("location:home.html");

}
    else{   $row = mysql_fetch_array($record);

    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
    $_SESSION["user_level"] = $row["user_level"]; 
    header("location: home.html");
}


mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Well, where and how do you set the values? Currently it can be seen, that if `user_id` is set, but `user_level` is not 2 it will always get redirected. Or, if the `user_id` is not set it will always get redirected too.

Comment: Which site contains that code?

Comment: also what file is this code found in?

Comment: Dont tell me that code is on bookTour.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirect loop if the file which contains that code is named bookTour.php or bookTour.php redirects back to the file that contains that code.